# jQuery Fade-in Workaround when Javascript isn't Available

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser

I've been using a jQuery fade-in on my homepage, and I've recently just realized that it shows a black screen when Javascript is disabled. How can I change remove the property `display: none` when Javascript isn't available?

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('html').fadeIn(3000);
   })
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: black url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat 200px center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: A 3-second fade-in when the page has loaded?  That seems excessive.

Comment: Instead do `$('html').hide().fadeIn(3000);`

Comment: @ExplosionPills I think that the body element is going to have to be hidden as soon as is possible, otherwise parts of it may render before the document-ready event is raised.

Comment: Why is that excessive? How would I fade in the content in a less excessive manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<noscript>
   <style type="text/css">
       body {display: block;}
   </style>
</noscript>
```

In your head section after the styles in your question will show the body.

or just add:

```
document.body.style.display = 'none';
```

in your javasript instead of hiding the body with CSS, as waiting for DOM ready will cause flickering.

Comment: `document.body.style.display = 'none';` is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Have it SHOWN by default.

Then in your JS, hide it immediately and have it fade back in.

This way it is shown by default (good) and you can still play around with whatever effects you need when jS is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that use the noscript tag in HTML:
    HTML

```
<noscript><div id='cover'></div></noscript>
```

CSS

```
#cover{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
   background-color:black
}
```

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to set the "display:none;" property programmatically. If its disabled its ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in your JS/CSS.

In your HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
```

In your CSS:

```
body {
    /* your styles */
}

body.js {
   display: none;
}
```

In your JS:

```
(function () {
    var $html = $('html').removeClass('no-js', 'js');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $html.fadeIn(3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant check if javascript is unavailable. You can check if javascript IS available tho, just by running any javascript.

first, I would define the display property in CSS as normal.
Then I would set to window.onload to change the display property to none.

This causes that when javascript is unavailable the code wont run and the display property will remain normal.

I dont know if I am answering your question exactly, let me know if I am not.